# scrolling the whole view up and down on appearance of keyboard on iPhone

Tags: iphone

How can I scroll the whole view up and down on appearance/disappearance of keyboard on iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the UICatalog sample project. TextFieldController.m - the function
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif
It really answers your question.